# Drawing the major and minor axis of an elliptical object in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

This program currently inputs an image of a coin, thresholds it, binarizes it, and finds the major and minor axis lengths of the segmented elliptical using the [regionprops](http://www.mathworks.se/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) function. How do I output a subplot where I draw the axes used to calculate the 'MajorAxisLength' and 'MinorAxisLength' over the original image?

I have appended my code for your perusal.

```
% Read in the image.
folder = 'C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\MATLAB\Work';
baseFileName = 'coin2.jpg';
fullFileName = fullfile(folder, baseFileName);
fullFileName = fullfile(folder, baseFileName);
if ~exist(fullFileName, 'file')
    fullFileName = baseFileName; % No path this time.
    if ~exist(fullFileName, 'file')
        %Alert user.
        errorMessage = sprintf('Error: %s does not exist.', fullFileName);
        uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
        return;
    end
end

rgbImage = imread(fullFileName);
% Get the dimensions of the image. numberOfColorBands should be = 3.
[rows columns numberOfColorBands] = size(rgbImage);
% Display the original color image.
subplot(2, 3, 1);
imshow(rgbImage, []);
title('Original color Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);
% Enlarge figure to full screen.
set(gcf, 'Position', get(0,'Screensize'));

% Extract the individual red color channel.
redChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 1);
% Display the red channel image.
subplot(2, 3, 2);
imshow(redChannel, []);
title('Red Channel Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);
% Binarize it
binaryImage = redChannel < 100;
% Display the image.
subplot(2, 3, 3);
imshow(binaryImage, []);
title('Thresholded Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);

binaryImage = imfill(binaryImage, 'holes');
labeledImage = bwlabel(binaryImage);

area_measurements = regionprops(labeledImage,'Area');
allAreas = [area_measurements.Area];
biggestBlobIndex = find(allAreas == max(allAreas));
keeperBlobsImage = ismember(labeledImage, biggestBlobIndex);
measurements = regionprops(keeperBlobsImage,'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength')

% Display the original color image with outline.
subplot(2, 3, 4);
imshow(rgbImage);
hold on;
title('Original Color Image with Outline', 'FontSize',fontSize);
boundaries = bwboundaries(keeperBlobsImage);
blobBoundary = boundaries{1};
plot(blobBoundary(:,2), blobBoundary(:,1), 'g-', 'LineWidth', 1);
hold off;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same task as you for some project I did 2 years ago. I've modified the code I used then for you below. It involved calculating the covariance matrix for the datapoints and finding their eigenvalues/eigenvectors. Note here that because of circular symmetry, the minor and major axis will be somewhat "random". Also note that I have made the image binary in a very naïve way to keep the code simple.

```
% Load data and make bw
clear all;close all; clc; 
set(0,'Defaultfigurewindowstyle','docked')

I = imread('american_eagle_gold_coin.jpg');
Ibw = im2bw(I,0.95);
Ibw = not(Ibw);

figure(1);clf
imagesc(Ibw);colormap(gray)

%% Calculate axis and draw

[M N] = size(Ibw);
[X Y] = meshgrid(1:N,1:M);

%Mass and mass center
m = sum(sum(Ibw));
x0 = sum(sum(Ibw.*X))/m;
y0 = sum(sum(Ibw.*Y))/m;

%Covariance matrix elements
Mxx = sum(sum((X-x0).^2.*Ibw))/m;
Myy = sum(sum((Y-y0).^2.*Ibw))/m;
Mxy = sum(sum((Y-y0).*(X-x0).*Ibw))/m;

MM = [Mxx Mxy; Mxy Myy];

[U S V] = svd(MM);

W = V(:,1)/sign(V(1,1)); %Extremal directions (normalized to have first coordinate positive)
H = V(:,2);
W = 2*sqrt(S(1,1))*W; %Scaling of extremal directions to give ellipsis half axis
H = 2*sqrt(S(2,2))*H;

figure(1)
hold on
    plot(x0,y0,'r*');
    quiver(x0,y0,W(1),H(1),'r')
    quiver(x0,y0,W(2),H(2),'r')
hold off
```

[image: Original image]
[image: Axis found from binary image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for writing all this up, it's exactly the assistance I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the documentation for the [Orientation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/regionprops.html#bqkf8ji) attribute that `regionprops()` can return to you.

This gives the angle between the positive x-axis and the major axis of the ellipse. You should be able to derive the equation for the major axis line in terms of that angle, and then just make a grid of x-axis points, and compute the major axis line's value for all the points in your grid, then just plot it like you would plot any other curve in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB).

To do the same for the minor axis, just note that it will be 90 degrees further counter-clockwise from the major axis, then repeat the step above.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the reputation required to upvote yet.

Answer (score 0):

Usually one does it with computing eigenvectors, as explained in the Wikipedia article *[Image moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment)* under 'examples'. That would be the correct way.

But I wonder, if you know the centroid and the boundingbox from MATLAB, then the endpoint of the major axis must be in the upper left or upper right corner. So checking (apart from noise) these two corners, if there are pixel, would give you the major axis. The minor axis then is just orthogonal to it with respect to the centroid.

Sorry for not having MATLAB code ready.

The reasoning is not that wrong, but not so good either, using the orientation as written above is better ;)

Comment: I appreciate you taking time to give me some input.