# Finding major axis/image orientation of binary image in R

Tags: image, r, matlab, image-processing, binary-data

I have a high res binary image which looks something like:

[image]

I'm trying to compute the major axis which should be slightly rotated to the right and eventually get the axis of orientation of the object

A post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984623/drawing-the-major-and-minor-axis-of-an-elliptical-object-in-matlab) (in matlab) suggests a way of doing this is computing the covariance matrix for the datapoints and finding their eigenvalues/eigenvectors

I am trying to implement something similar in R

```
%% MATLAB CODE Calculate axis and draw

[M N] = size(Ibw);
[X Y] = meshgrid(1:N,1:M);

%Mass and mass center
m = sum(sum(Ibw));
x0 = sum(sum(Ibw.*X))/m;
y0 = sum(sum(Ibw.*Y))/m;
```

---

```
#R code

d = dim(im)
M = d[1]
N = d[2]

t = meshgrid(M,N)
X = t[[2]]
Y = t[[1]]
m = sum(im);
x0 = sum(im %*% X)/m;
y0 = sum(im %*% Y)/m;

meshgrid <-function(r,c){
  return(list(R=matrix(rep(1:r, r), r, byrow=T), 
          C=matrix(rep(1:c, c), c)))
}
```

However, computing `m` , `x0` and `y0` takes too long in R.

Does anyone know of an implementation in R?

Comment: can you use `system.time()` and find out which line is taking more time?

Comment: Its the matrix multiplication. My image is `2736x3648`

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: Mac OSX x64 mountain lion

Comment: Since your image is made of straight edges, you could also use the [Hough transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to detect them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing the variance matrix directly, with `var`, takes 1/3 of a second.

```
# Sample data
M <- 2736
N <- 3648
im <- matrix( FALSE, M, N );
y <- as.vector(row(im))
x <- as.vector(col(im))
im[ abs( y - M/2 ) < M/3 & abs( x - N/2 ) < N/3 ] <- TRUE
#image(im)
theta <- runif(1, -pi/12, pi/12)
xy <- cbind(x+1-N/2,y+1-M/2) %*% matrix(c( cos(theta), sin(theta), -sin(theta), cos(theta) ), 2, 2)
#plot(xy[,1]+N/2-1, xy[,2]+M/2-1); abline(h=c(1,M),v=c(1,N))
f <- function(u, lower, upper) pmax(lower,pmin(round(u),upper))
im[] <- im[cbind( f(xy[,2] + M/2 - 1,1,M), f(xy[,1] + N/2 - 1,1,N) )]
image(1:N, 1:M, t(im), asp=1)

# Variance matrix of the points in the rectangle
i <- which(im)
V <- var(cbind( col(im)[i], row(im)[i] ))
# Their eigenvectors
u <- eigen(V)$vectors
abline( M/2-N/2*u[2,1]/u[1,1], u[2,1]/u[1,1], lwd=5 )
abline( M/2-N/2*u[2,2]/u[1,2], u[2,2]/u[1,2] )
```

[image: Binary image, with major and minor axes]

Comment: Clean. Concise. Fast. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the default Rblas.dll with a suitable one from [this link](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/ATLAS/).